# Updating item array using knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I am pretty new at using KnockoutJS as a framework, and I (obviously) encountered a question I cannot (or more likely, am not skilled enough to) find.

I have this product group and each product group contains array of products. Now, I managed to display a list of product groups and a list of all products without much problem. I want to increase product quantity, when user left-clicks a div containing product and decrease product quantity when user right-clicks a div containing products.

I have set up event handlers correctly as they get fired and handled without any problems and quantity is changed, but I cannot seem to get it to reflect on the page.

Markup:

```
<div class="viewProductGroup" data-bind="with: productGroupData">
    <h2 data-bind="text: Title"></h2>
    <div class="stickies" data-bind="foreach: Products">
        <div data-bind="click: $root.addProduct, 
                        event: { contextmenu: $root.removeProduct }">
            <span data-bind="text: Title"></span><br />(<span data-bind="text: Quantity"></span>)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Excerpt from JS:

```
function StickyExViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.productGroupData = ko.observable();

    // Behaviors
    self.addProduct = function (item) {
        item.Quantity++;
    }
    self.removeProduct = function (item) {
        item.Quantity--;
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new StickyExViewModel());
```

Now, I am sure I don't understand something or have missed some wiring. Can you please help?

**Edit**

Here is JSON obtained from WCF service:

```
{"d":
    {"__type":"ProductGroup:#Stickyex.Services",
     "Created":"\/Date(1373407200000+0200)\/",
     "ID":1,
     "Products":[
        {"__type":"Product:#Stickyex.Services","Code":"0","ID":0,"Quantity":0,"Title":"0"},
        {"__type":"Product:#Stickyex.Services","Code":"1","ID":1,"Quantity":1,"Title":"1"},
        {"__type":"Product:#Stickyex.Services","Code":"2","ID":2,"Quantity":2,"Title":"2"}],
     "Title":"ProductGroup 1"}
}
```

Code to obtain JSON data (inside StickyExViewModel):

```
self.goToProductGroup = function(productGroup) {
    $.get(serviceUrl, { ixProductGroup: productGroup.ID }, function (data) {
        self.productGroupData(data.d);
    });
}
```

Comment: how do you get your data for product groups?? maybe you are accessing them in a wrong way

Comment: then do you use what to create your array?? ko.mapping.fromJSON()??

Comment: I get JSON data from WCF service with $.get jQuery function.

Comment: can you write the code you use to convert your JSON into array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you who tried to and succeeded in helping me, I came to a final solution. In order to update Quantity, I should not bind to JSON object directly, but instead create classes in JS that represent a model of a JSON object.

```
function Product(item) {
    this.ID = item.ID;
    this.Title = item.Title;
    this.Quantity = ko.observable(item.Quantity);
}

function ProductGroup(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.ID = data.ID;
    this.Title = data.Title;
    this.Products = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Products.length; i++) {
        self.Products.push(new Product(data.Products[i]));
    }
}
```

And the part where I obtain JSON was changed to:

```
self.goToProductGroup = function(productGroup) {
    $.get(serviceUrl, { ixProductGroup: productGroup.ID }, function (data) {
        self.productGroupData($.map(data, function (pg) {
            return new ProductGroup(pg);
        }));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that item.Quantity is observable so you cannot use increment and decrement to it. Each observable is a function so you have to use `()` to get or set value:

```
// Behaviors
self.addProduct = function (item) {
    item.Quantity(item.Quantity() + 1);
}
self.removeProduct = function (item) {
    item.Quantity(item.Quantity() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Quantity property needs to be an obsevable.
So in StickyExViewModel you will able to do this :

```
function StickyExViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.productGroupData = ko.observable();

    // Behaviors
    self.addProduct = function (item) {
        item.Quantity( item.Quantity()++);
    }
    self.removeProduct = function (item) {
        item.Quantity( item.Quantity()--);
    }
}
```

By converting the Quantity into an observable, your Gui will be refreshed a soon as you change the property.

Comment: How do I convert an item in an array of an array to observable though?

Comment: In the Product contructor write : self.Quantity = ko.observable(0);
Instead of self.Quantity = 0;

Comment: Aha. So basically, I shouldn't bind directly to JSON object, but instead map it to JS objects with similar properties?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to make little modification on the way you convert your `productGroupData` into observable object.

First: `productGroupData` should be `observableArray` not `observable` because it's actually an array.
`self.productGroupData = ko.observableArray([]);`

Second to convert your JSON string into that `observableArray` you can take advantage of [KnockoutJS mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). This 'll make your coding a lot much better. So you can use it to convert your JSON into an `observableArray`

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(yourJS_Object, {}, self.productGroupData);//in case you have JS object
```

OR

```
ko.mapping.fromJSSON(yourJSON_String, {}, self.productGroupData);//in case you have JSON string.
```

Notice now all your properties or objects of your `productGroupData` are observables so to access them you need to use `()`

Comment: productGroupData is not an array. It is an item containing an array.

Comment: In original post, you can see, I assign to self.productGroupData value of data.d, not data. Property "d" is just a thing that WCF services attach to JSON response they generate. So, basically, root item of self.productGroupData is an item where "__type":"ProductGroup:#Stickyex.Services" is defined.